# Changing cursor in mouse hook

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I need to change the cursor in my mouse hook procedure but I cannot find a way

If I change the cursor with the function `SetSystemCursor` , it changes but whenever it is moved onto different window (lets say a window that change the cursor `IDC_ARROR` to `IDC_HAND`, or something like this) , puff, the cursor changes again.

In my mouse hook procedure, even if I call `SetCursor` function at the beginning of the procedure, nothing changes. (though I don't call `CallNextHook` and set the cursor position using `SetCursorPos` function).

What should I do, any ideas?

Comment: That may not be possible in winapi. We are talking about winapi, right?

Comment: You may need to set up a global API hook on whatever function is responsible for changing the cursor and just force it to return success and make it fail.

Comment: yes, i'm talking about winapi. 
if i set all cursors to my own cursor with setsystemcursor api function, it's good but i know that it is not the formal way to do that  and the programs using their own special cursors won't be affected by this method.

Comment: and sorry for late answer